# How to center pseudo element on an unknown sized text parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to draw circles around numbers that appear within a paragraph. Numbers will either be one or two digits. I'de like the circles to not affect the line-height of my text.

I can hard-code the absolute positioning and it works fine if the numbers are one digit, but the same values won't work for two digits. Is there a way to position the pseudo element so that it will center regardless of whether it's one or two digits?

```css
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 32px;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.15em;
  font-family: Proxima Nova, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.number-pick--in-text {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 10px;
}


.number-pick--in-text::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  top: -1px;
  right: -12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #79818B;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <p class="article--text">
    Brandon used his own birthday for his lucky lotto numbers. He picked 
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">1</span> 
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">3</span> 
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">9</span> 
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">12</span> 
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">43</span>  
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">4</span>. 
    He bought his ticket at a local convience store and found out the next day that he won the $150 million jackpot.
  </p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not really need the pseudo, vertical-align + size will do

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align
>
> The `vertical-align` CSS property sets vertical alignment of an inline or table-cell box.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 32px;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.15em;
  font-family: Proxima Nova, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.number-pick--in-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;/* adjust value to your needs */
  text-align:center;  
  width: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #79818B;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <p class="article--text">
    Brandon used his own birthday for his lucky lotto numbers. He picked 
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">1</span> 
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">3</span> 
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">9</span> 
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">12</span> 
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">43</span>  
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">4</span>. 
    He bought his ticket at a local convience store and found out the next day that he won the $150 million jackpot.
  </p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard method:

```
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 32px;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.15em;
  font-family: Proxima Nova, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.number-pick--in-text {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 10px;
}


.number-pick--in-text::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #79818B;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <p class="article--text">
    Brandon used his own birthday for his lucky lotto numbers. He picked 
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">1</span> 
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">3</span> 
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">9</span> 
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">12</span> 
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">43</span>  
    <span class="number-pick--in-text">4</span>. 
    He bought his ticket at a local convience store and found out the next day that he won the $150 million jackpot.
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, but leaves me with unequal spacing between my two digit and one digits elements.

Comment: *Is there a way to position the pseudo element so that it will center regardless of whether it's one or two digits?* was your question. *How to center pseudo element on an unknown sized text parent* is your question title. My answer does exactly that, in contrast to the picked answer.